# In JavaScript, is it possible to have to audio input as a event listener? (Idea construction)

Tags: javascript, html, audio, webrtc

There is an idea which I have been toying with for the past few weeks. I am extremely serious to realise this concept, but I totally lack any know how about the implementation. I have some thoughts which I'll be sharing as I explain what the idea is.

We have websites. Most of them are responsive.

What is [responsive web design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design)?

By and large, responsive web design means that design and development should respond to the user’s behaviour and environment based on screen size, platform and orientation. If I change my window size, my website to should change its dimensions accordingly.
If I scale some object on the screen, then the website should rearrange/ rescale accordingly.

This is good, but nothing exciting (nowadays!).

I am again so damnfully limited by a screen and to whatever happening inside it that what I do outside seems still very external and not seamless. Except my contact with the mouse/ keyboard, I do not know any other way to communicate with the things that happen inside the screen. My screen experience is still a very external feature, not seamless with my cognition. I think this is also a reason why my computer always remains a computer and does not behave a natural extension of the human body.

I was toying with a idea which I have no clue how to realize. I have a basic idea, but I need some some technical/ design help from those who are fascinated by this as much as I am.

The idea is simple: Make the screen more responsive, but this time without use of a mouse or any such input device. All laptops and most desktops have a microphone. How about using this small device for input?

Let me explain:

Imagine, a website in which screen icons repopulate when you blow a whiff onto the screen. The song on your favourite playlist changes when you whistle to the screen.

Say you have an animated tree on the screen. That tree sheds its leaves when you blow air to it. The shedding depends on how fast you blow. Getting a small idea?

Let me put some graphics (see the hyperlink after this paragraph) which I think will make it better. I plan to make a website/ API in which there is a person with long hair staring at you. If you blow air from the right side of your screen, her hair moves to the left. If you blow air from the left, her hair blows to the right. If you blow faint, her hair suffers faint scattering. Some naughty stuff, say you whistle: The character on the screen winks, or say throws a disgusting expression- whatever.

The whole concept is that every element of the web must have a direct relation with the user who is sitting outside the screen. It gives a whole lot of realism to the website architecture if things like my whistle, whiff or say even my sneeze can do something to the website! I am not tied to the mouse or the keyboard for my response to be noted. Doesn’t that reduce a hell of a lot of cognitive load on the user?

See this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZF80M.jpg

Now coming to the technical aspect that I need guidance on.

If I was building a regular responsive website in JavaScript, I'd use addeventhandler("Click", Animate) or addeventhandler("resize", Animate) - something like that. Here I want my event handler to be the audio input that is coming from the microphone. Also, I need to know the place from where the audio is originating that I can decide which side the hair must fall and play that animation.

So in the span of 180/360 degree of the microphone, I need to not just catch the audio, but also its angle that the right animation can be played. It'd be a crashing fail if the same animation is played where-ever I blow air. It needs to have that element of realism.

I have asked around and some people suggested to me that I try [WebRTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebRTC) of HTML5. I am still seeing if that works, but otherwise are there any more options? I guess [Processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_%28programming_language%29) is one. Has anyone handled its audio features?

I want to build a simple prototype first before I delve into the immense possibilities this idea could have. But if you have some really awesome thing in mind, please let me know about it. Exciting ideas are one thing, and exciting implementation totally another. We want both.
Are there such websites already? Any work happening in this side?

Any small guidance counts!

Comment: mic input is mono, so this is a no-go afaik.

Comment: @dandavis: A stereo Mic could be arranged, but beyond that how do I ensure that I get my mic audio input as a event handler in Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to create your own events. Most libraries have some built-in way of doing so. Basically you're talking about the [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) and here's a nice article to explain it in greater detail: https://dottedsquirrel.com/javascript/observer-pattern/

Also as far as listening to audio goes, using an analyzer-node (*[AnalyserNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode)*) on the input signal and some ingenious code to determine that the sound is what you want to listen to, firing the event is a piece of cake using aforementioned custom events.

But, before diving into those, determining the angle of the sound? I do not think that is even possible. You *might* be able to determine the angle of the origin of the sound in a '2d' scope, but that certainly won't give you an angle. I think you'd need something rather more ingenious than a simple stereo mic setup to determine the angle.

Comment: I looked into the observer pattern link you mentioned. It seems preety much what I want to do. Someone suggested to me that I try Web Audio API. It has built in library for Live audio processing as a event. 
I've more/less compromised on having to determine the angle of the audio.I am first making a simple modest try at having Live audio from the mic being a trigger for animation on the webpage.

Comment: The first link is (effectively) broken - it redirects to the main page.